# Unterminated quoted string (Perl)

Tags: perl

I am using a new version of perl to run some old script. This is my perl version:

```
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi (with 67 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

I am Very confusing about this line in the script, which just keeping error, though the program is runable. Maybe it's b/c the script was written for quite a while and perl has made some syntax change? Below is the line:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
if($#ARGV != 0||$ARGV[0] eq "--help"){ print STDERR "Split bed file into one file per chromosome (keeping and adjusting the header)\n\nUsage: split_bed <BED file>"; }
```

The error message is:

```
 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string --hel_  N     N'th byte, character or field, counted from 1p
```

Can anyone help me to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Perl error. Perl would have said:

```
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF
```

It seems the shell can produce similar error, though:

```
echo 'x="a' | sh
sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

How do you run the script? Does it contain a shebang line? Try running it with explicit `perl`:

```
 perl script.pl
```

Comment: Hi Choroba Thank you. I just find some release instructions from wiki. That actually fixed my problem. There is a "$#ARGV != 0||$ARGV[0] eq "--help"" in the 3rd line.

Comment: The phrase `N      N'th byte, character or field, counted from 1` oddly seems to come from the manual page of the `cut` command ...

Comment: Wait...simply run the script without argument is fine. But when I add "--help", the error came again and no stderr messages at all..

Comment: I had tried perl script.pl... It's still error..

Answer (score 0):

I just searched history for my question. Since 5.10.0, perl has "New defined-or operator (//)".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_5_version_history

Thank you~

Comment: How is this related to your question? The code sample nor the error message contains the operator.